# USB considered as COM port

Tags: serial-port, usb

Why most of devices connected to a PC via USB are considered as connected to COM port? As I've read, COM port is referred to RS232 serial port with DB9 connector, that is nowadays mounted rarely in devices.

There comes also another question - why most of devices connected to USB are using USB to UART converters? Is it because of high complexity level of USB standard?

Comment: The huge majority of USB devices such as flash drives, external disks, cameras, scanners, audio equipment etc. do NOT use RS232 serial communication and do not appear as COM ports. What kind of devices are you talking about, or why do you think they all use serial communication?

Comment: Okay, that's my fault, because I am checking assignments of COM ports mostly in situations, when I have connected devices (dev kits) with USB to UART converter, in order to read some kind of data.